# How accurate is client unix time?

Tags: time, unix-timestamp

I'm curious about how accurate a client's browser/javascript unix time is, as I don't have a very good understanding of digital/computer timekeeping.

For instance, if my sever tells the client to do something at a given unix time, will it actually happen at the same time on multiple computers in the US and Europe and China?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[Unix time, or POSIX time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), is a system for describing instants in time, defined as the number of seconds elapsed since midnight Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) of Thursday, January 1, 1970 (Unix times are defined, but negative, before that date), not counting leap seconds, which are declared by the International Earth Rotation and Reference Systems Service.

The link provided is a really good link and gives comparisons to other time systems. I strongly recommend you look there.

Comment: Thanks!  Is it reasonably to assume that computers nowadays have a fairly accurate unix time?  Is it reliable enough to do synchronization?

Comment: @GarenCheckley I would presume so, but I don't know that much about it to say for sure

Comment: @Garen, I would say no - unless one takes specific action to ensure accuracy. It also depends on the amount of accuracy you require, of course =)

Answer (score 1):

Probably not, since computer clock time tends to be rather arbitrary.

However, if you control all of those computers and can ensure that it is synchronized using NTP or some such service, you might be able to sync all of those actions even using Javascript.

I wouldn't trust client time on the World Wide Web.